# How to convert Django's TimeField to Postgres' timestamp with time zone

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, timestamp

In my Django app, the program gets the time of an event from the user, say user inputs 10:30 for the time of an event.  The program uses modelformset_factory to create a whole bunch of forms:

```
#forms.py
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['entry', 'time', 'work']
        localized_fields = ('time', )
        widgets = {
        'work': Textarea(attrs = {'cols': 40, 'rows': 8}),
        }

#models.py
class Event(models.Model):
    '''
    Each day there are many events, e.g. at 10 am, the framer orders material, etc.
    '''
    entry = models.ForeignKey(Entry)
    time = models.TimeField()
    work = models.TextField()


#views.py:

EventFormSet = modelformset_factory( Event, form = EventForm, exclude = ('entry',),extra = 5)

eventset = self.EventFormSet(request.POST)

all_errors = eventset.errors # All errors returns [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}], so the data is free of error.
try:
    eventset.is_valid()             
except ValidationError:
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': self.day_log(initial = self.initial_values), 'eventforms': self.event_formset})
events_instances = eventset.save(commit = False)

for instance in events_instances:
    if instance.time:
        event_date = datetime.date(the_year, the_month, the_day) # Naive date
        event_time = instance.time # Naive time
        naive_event_time = timezone.is_naive(event_time) # Checking naivaty 
        event_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(event_date, event_time) # Naive datetime object
        is_aware_event_datetime = timezone.is_aware(event_datetime) # Checking to see if the datetime object is aware or naive
        event_aware_datetime = datetime.datetime(the_year, the_month, the_day, instance.time.hour, instance.time.minute, instance.time.second, tzinfo = pytz.utc) # Making an aware time
        is_aware_event_aware_datetime = timezone.is_aware(event_aware_datetime) # Making sure the event_aware_datetime is indeed aware
        instance.time = event_aware_datetime
        awareness_test = timezone.is_aware(instance.time) # Making sure instance.time is aware
        eventset.save()  # Here is where the exception is thrown.
```

The Django app fails to save time data to Postgres.  The exception type is DataError with the exception value:

```
invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: 
LINE 1: ...y_event" ("entry_id", "time", "work") VALUES (14, '18:43:04....
```

with ^ pointing at ' of '18:

Edit:
Here is my database:

```
CREATE TABLE site_activity_event
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    entry_id integer NOT NULL,
    "time" time without time zone NOT NULL,
     work text NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT site_activity_event_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
     CONSTRAINT site_activity_event_entry_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (entry_id)
        REFERENCES site_activity_entry (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
    )
```

I did sqlall my app to ensure that the data type of model field correspond to that of the app and all is well there.  This seems to be a postgres issue, but Django is supposed to take care of all those pesky interface issues with Postgres (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/#migration-guide), so that makes me think I am missing something.  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: show your `request.POST`

Answer (score 0):

Well, is "18:43:04" a valid timestamp with a timezone? Do you think it specifies a unique point in time? If you do then you have uncovered a major bug in PostgreSQL's date/time handling. If not, then you should either supply a valid timestamp or use the correct type in your database - I can't say which without knowing more about these events.

Comment: The problem is when the user enters 09:00, Django should serve this to Postgres in the format Postgres can accept.  It clearly does not.  I even tried to manually create an object of the similar format for each instance of my modelformset, but it gets messy when it comes to add the timezone.

Comment: I take it that you mean the timezone needs to be explicitly mentioned to avoid ambiguity. The problem is when the user enters 09:00, Django should serve this to Postgres in the format Postgres can accept.  It clearly does not.  Now, my three hour research showed me that this might have to do with the fact that I did not have pytz setup.  So, I did this: event_awaretime = pytz.timezone("Canada/Pacific").localize(event_datetime, is_dst = None) and then for each instance of my formset, I did this:  instance.time = event_awaretime. I get the same error though!  There should be a simpler way.

Comment: It's still not a timestamp. Have you looked at the PostgreSQL documentation for what a timestamp actually *is*?

Comment: OK, the question is how to convert simple 9:10 input into acceptable Postgres input.  I understand that the naive time should be converted into aware time and the tzinfo should be included too:    event_aware_datetime = pytz.timezone("Canada/Pacific").localize(event_datetime, is_dst = None).  But, the problem is even this is not acceptable to Postgres.  I wish you could explain in detail how to do this.  I am a beginner in both and after hours of reading I am here to ask other experts.

Comment: "9:10" is not even a time - it could be in the morning or the night. It doesn't make sense to add a regional timezone (e.g. "Europe/London") to it without a date too. A timestamp represents a point in time, e.g. "Thu 23 Jul 23:31:47 BST 2015". So - either you want a "time" in the database or a "timestamp" in your application. This isn't really anything to do with databases or even computing. It's a basic understanding of units.

Comment: You are right!  That is why in the app, the program changes the input to a naive time first: event_time = instance.time.  I get datetime.time(9,10).  Then, I make a naive datetime object by combining the date and time fields in the form: event_datetime = datetime.datetime.combinte(event_date, event_time).  And, I change it to an aware object: event_aware_datetime = datetime.datetime(the_year, the_month, the_day, instance.time.hour, instance.time.minute, instance.time.second, tzinfo = pytz.utc).   When I print it, I get 2015-07-23 09:10:00-07:00.

Comment: The problem is when I try to write that value to the database: instance.time = event_aware_datetime, it still complains: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "09:10:00".  So, for some reason, the aware time which should qualify as Postgres timestamp is not passed as a timestamp.  This is the problem and I apologize if I did not provide a sufficiently thorough and clear description of the problem earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your Event has a TimeField but it looks like the database was created with a DateTimeField.

Comment: I edited my post to show the database sql.  Please elaborate

Comment: @EarlyCoder - Is that the sql output from Django?  Try looking at the created tables is postgres.  The error says "invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone" but your sqlall doesn't mention any `timestamp with time zone` which leads me to believe that your database schema doesn't match .